# Reference existing CF project models

Tags: codefluent

We have multiple model projects using codefluent (M1 and M2).

Is it possible to have one model project (say M1) using type reference of another model project (M2) ?

I tried adding project reference or existing item in model but none of them worked.
The import feature doesn't seem to be the way to go either

Shall I consider having only one model project for my solution ?

Thanks for your answer,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to create a relationship between entities of both models.
If so, it's easier to have only one model. If you create multiple models because of their sizes, you may be interested in parts and surfaces to split it ([blog post about surfaces](http://blog.codefluententities.com/2012/06/20/codefluent-entities-multiple-surfaces-multiple-parts/)).

If you want to have multiple models, I think it's possible to create relationships between entities (*but I didn't test it*). You need to create the entity in both model and play with the producer specific attribute `enabled` (`cfps:enabled`, `cfom:enabled`, etc.). Unless you really want to do complex things, I think you may stick to one model.

Comment: Sticking with one model project seems also to me the way to go, Thanks for your answer.